# how to debug java script error?

Tags: javascript

i am using around 200 lines of java script  in my jsp page, but while logging into my  application javascript error is throwing.. like below

```
 Line :1045

 char : 15 

 Error : Expected ')'

 Code : 0

 URL : https://locahhost:9443/gchweb/showWelcome.do
```

how to rectify it.(my total page size is around 400 only including jsp tags).
help me on this. i am struggling a lot.

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help you out without more information, particularly the code around where the error claims the problem is.

Comment: Use Chrome's built in inspector, or Firebug in Firefox to look at the error and even step through the code to get to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line number is per the source of the page on the client (i.e. use view source in the browser),  not per the source of the page on the server.  Presumably it's much longer on the client.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you can' find Line 1045 because you have dynamic content in the same page.

If you use firefox+firebug you'll be able to click the error in the javascript console to show the content of the line.

Answer (score 2):

The line number is not the line in the JSP source code, it's the line in the generated page that the browsers sees.

Use the View Source function in your browser to see which line it is that is causing the error.